# mobx-react-lite useObserver hook outside of render

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

I've seen examples of the useObserver hook that look like this:

```
const Test = () => {

  const store = useContext(storeContext); 

  return useObserver(() => (
    <div> 
      <div>{store.num}</div>
    </div>
  ))

}
```

But the following works too, and I'd like to know if there's any reason not to use useObserver to return a value that will be used in render rather than to return the render.

```
const Test = () => {

  const store = useContext(storeContext); 

  var num = useObserver(function (){
    return store.num;
  });

  return (
    <div> 
      <div>{num}</div>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Also, I don't get any errors using useObserver twice in the same component.  Any problems with something like this?

```
const Test = () => {

  const store = useContext(storeContext); 

  var num = useObserver(function (){
    return store.num;
  });

  return useObserver(() => (
    <div> 
      <div>{num}</div>
      <div>{store.num2}</div>
    </div>
  ))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **observer** method in the component. And use any store you want.

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { useStore } from "../../stores/StoreContext";

    
    const Test = observer(() => {

          const { myStore } = useStore();
                
          return() => (
            <div> 
              <div>{myStore.num}</div>
              <div>{myStore.num2}</div>
            </div>
          )
        
        }
    );
```

StoreContext.ts

```
import myStore from './myStore'
export class RootStore{
        //Define your stores here. also import them in the imports
         myStore = newMyStore(this)
        }
    
    export const rootStore = new RootStore();
    
    const StoreContext = React.createContext(rootStore);
    
    export const useStore = () => React.useContext(StoreContext);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I'm specifically asking whether observer has to wrap the render the part and if you can use it twice in a component.

Comment: No, You have to wrap the enter component inside the observer method.

Comment: I appreciate this other way of thinking about it, so thanks.  That makes 4 ways it can work: around render, around a var, around both, and around the component.  The official docs do show it though only around render: https://mobx-react.js.org/observer-hook